# C# Form error with inputing data, not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, forms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form5 : Form
{
     private Pickups thePickups;
    //The pickups object being created/edited


    public Pickups appointment
    {   //Property to allow access to thePickups
        get { return thePickups; }
        set { thePickups = value; }
    }


    public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thePickups.custName = textBox1.Text;
        thePickups.custAddress= textBox2.Text;
        thePickups.arrival = textBox3.Text;
        thePickups.delAddress = textBox4.Text;
        thePickups.delName = textBox5.Text;


        this.Hide();
        //Hide the form
    }

    private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



      if (thePickups != null)
        {
            textBox1.Text = thePickups.custName;
            textBox2.Text = thePickups.delAddress.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = thePickups.arrival.ToString();
        } 
    }
    }
}
```

I get an error saying that - Object reference is not set to an instance of an object, this is one of many files in my project but its the first one I've had any errors with. I'm struggling to see where I've made my mistake here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the floating period toward the bottom of your code block?

Comment: Where are you get the exception?

Comment: Well where are you setting `appointment`? You need to make sure that `thePickups` will be non-null before you click the button, but I don't think you're doing that anywhere...

Comment: You do not mention a line where the error happens. Just an advice: in Visual Studio go to Debug/Exceptions menu and there check Common language runtime exceptions: thrown and Unhandled. Then when running in debug your app will stop when an exception is thrown and you see the place.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, its the first line after my button click, thePickups.custName=textBox1.Text;

Answer (score 0):

Is it me going blind or do I not see a line

```
thePickups = new Pickups();
```

anywhere?

As an aside, form.Hide looks dodgy too. Are you really sure you want it there but hidden? But that won't account for your exception.

Answer (score 0):

You define `thePickups` with;

```
 private Pickups thePickups;
//The pickups object being created/edited


public Pickups appointment
{   //Property to allow access to thePickups
    get { return thePickups; }
    set { thePickups = value; }
}
```

But never set to an instance of object. And then, you try to check if this instance of ojbect is `null` or not.

```
if (thePickups != null)
{

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm getting confused I though when I defined thePickups that would create an instance of the object

Comment: No, you just define the class, not creating an instance of object.

Comment: private Pickups thePickups just defines a variable of type Pickups. To create an instance of the class Pickups you have to use thePickups = new Pickups();

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are setting some value in the property you have created "appointment". Also do this on your button_click event.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(thePickups != null)
    {
        thePickups.custName = textBox1.Text;
        thePickups.custAddress= textBox2.Text;
        thePickups.arrival = textBox3.Text;
        thePickups.delAddress = textBox4.Text;
        thePickups.delName = textBox5.Text;


        this.Hide();
        //Hide the form
    }
}
```